# Show that the system has at least one limit cycle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, limit-cycles

$$x' = -y + x(1-2x^2 - 3y^2)$$
$$y' = x + y(1-2x^2 - 3y^2)$$

I've started by converting to polar coordinates
$$x=rcos\theta \quad y = rsin\theta, \quad rr'=xx'+yy'$$
This gives me
$$r' = 1-2r^2cos^2\theta-3r^2sin^2\theta$$.

I'm not sure where to go from here to show that I've got a limit cycle. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Whay results do you know about limit cycles?

Comment: Check the last formula again, you are missing a factor $r$ for the right side.

Comment: This task has the same general structure $x'=-y+a(x,y)x$, $y'=x+a(x,y)y$ like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3970981/prove-that-the-system-has-a-single-limit-cycle.

Comment: And you should also determine $\theta'$, not just $r'$.